# Understanding basic recursion function in Java to calculate positive integers in array

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to learn recursion in Java and have an array that takes in continuous input until the Scanner reads in a 0.

From there I have a method that (attempts) to calculate the number of positive integers in the array using recursion. This is the first recursive function I have ever written and I keep getting a stackoverflow error.

I have read tutorials and I still can't wrap my head around the basic understanding of recursion.

```
public class reuncF {

    private static int start = 0;
    private static int end = 98;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

           input = input.nextDouble();
           list[i] = numInput;

        computeSumPositive(numList, count);
    }

        }
        return positives += solve(numbers, count++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't deface your question. I've returned it to the state that the answers address.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to stop your recursion!

There has to be some case where `computeSumPositive` returns *without* calling itself again. Otherwise it'll just keep going forever, never getting back to you.

If you did it with a loop, the loop would look like this:

```
int positives = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numList.length; ++i) {
    if (numList[i] > 0) {
       positives++;
    }
}
```

To do that recursively, you just find out what are the variables used in the loop. They are `i`, `numList` and `positives`.

```
computeSumPositive(int i, double[] numList, int positives)
```

Then we take a look at what the loop does. First, it checks whether we went too far, 
so our recursive function should do that too. It'll have to return instead of just falling through like the loop does. And obviously, it must return the result:

```
{
    if (! (i < numList.length)) 
        return positives;
```

The loop then does the test and maybe increments `positives`, so the recursive function should also do that:

```
    if (numList[i] > 0) {
        positives++;
    }
```

At the end of the loop, `i` is updated:

```
    i++;
```

The loop just starts over, but the recursive function will have to call itself. Of course, we want it to use the new value of `i` and `positives`, but fortunately we updated those, so now we can just do:

```
    return computeSumPositives (i, numList, positives);
}
```

The tricky bit is that the values `i`, `numList`, and are *local to each call*. Each invocation of `computeSumPositives` can see only the arguments it were given. If it changes them, none of the other invocation can see that change.

EDIT: So if we, for reasons we can only speculate about, wanted *desperately* for `computeSumPositive` to take only 2 parameters, we would have to "split up" `positives` across each invocation. Each invocation knows whether or not its number was positive or not; all we have to do is add them. Then it looks like this:

```
computeSumPositive(int i, double[] numList)
{
    if (! (i < numList.length)) 
        return 0;  // I didn't find any at index i

    if (numList[i] > 0) {
        // Theres one I found + however many my later
        // invocations will find. 
        return 1 + computeSumPositive (i+1, numList);
    } else {
        // I didn't find any, but my later invocations might.
        return computeSumPositive (i+1, numList);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I added return positives at the end and I still get the error.

Comment: So, why would it increment if numList[i] < 0 when I want only positive values?

Comment: Do I basically want to iterate through the loop using the count variable? I can only do this using two parameters is the issue.

Comment: Basically. Since `numList` is never changed, it could be a field instead of a parameter, perhaps?

Comment: I am req. to pass it through as a parameter

Comment: YES I GOT IT, HAPPIEST PERSON IN THE WORLD RIGHT NOW!

Comment: Nvm... now I am back to the drawing board.

Comment: Ok, there we go, just got it finalized. Thanks for the help man

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful, when dealing with recursion, to figure out the termination case first.

It looks like you are treating 'count' as an index. So you could check if your at the last index in the array, if so and if the value is positive return a 1, if the value is non-positive return a 0 - dont recurse anymore.

If your not at the  last index, and the value is positive return a 1 + the recursive function call, or if the value is non-positive just continue to recurse.

This will still cause a stack overflow for large arrays.

Comment: It will still cause a stack overflow for little tiny arrays if he doesn't fix the other problem.

Answer (score -1):

The value of `count++` is the same as the value of `count`; the program uses the value and *then* increments it.  But the result is that `computeSumPositive` keeps calling itself with the same value of `count`, which leads to infinite recursion.  Note that each time `computeSumPositive` calls another `computeSumPositive`, each call has its *own* copy of the parameters (like `count`) and the local variables; so incrementing one `computeSumPositive`'s copy of `count` has no effect on the value of `count` used by other recursive calls.

Change `count++` to `count + 1`, and also add a way to halt the recursion.  (At some point, you will be calling `computeSumPositive` to look at zero integers, and at that point, it should just return 0 and not call itself.  You need to think about: how do you test whether you've reached that point?)

Comment: I am still lost with this explanation. I am more confused on my required code to halt the execution of the recursive function.

Comment: I think that `computeSumPositive` calls itself no matter the value of `count` is.

Comment: @user3491425 Here's a hint: Fix the `count++` problem as I've suggested, then try again and see what happens.  It should throw an exception (something other than stack overflow).  The exception may help you figure out what to do.

Comment: Still throws stack overflow

Comment: Ah, now I just get straight recursion error and index out of bounds 100. Still lost on the recursion issue.

Comment: You are getting an out-of-bounds exception because `count` is 100, i.e. `numbers.length`.  So `computeSumPositive` should not call itself if the second parameter would be `numbers.length`.

Comment: @user3491425 When `computeSumPositive` calls itself with a second parameter equal to 100.